# git rebase -i conflict

Tags: git, git-rebase

Мне нужно поменять местами 2 коммита, первый коммит добавлят в конец файла код, второй коммит добавляет ещё код, как их поменять местами без конфликтов?

Comment: Никак. Разруливать конфликт вручную

Comment: что значит вручную? просто обычно под ручным как я понимаю имеется ввиду отредактировать файлы нужные и сделать разрешающий коммит, а мне нужно просто чтобы коммиты поменялись местами и новые коммиты создавать не вариант. Получается нужно просто удалить оба коммита и закомитить их в правильном порядке?

Comment: значит что при rebase поменять строки коммитов и, возможно, все произойдет автоматически. А может и нет - никто не видел, что именно там коммитилось и как.

Comment: Вот вы поменяли коммиты местами, сначала идёт второй: что должно в этот момент быть в файле?